# How to stop Vim from writing onto system clipboard when visually selecting texts

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am using Vim 7.4.423 on a Windows 7 machine.

I notice that Vim will copy to system clipboard of whatever texts that I have "highlighted" through Visual mode. Is there a way to stop him from do this?

The "overwriting of clipboard upon enter visual mode" does not differ whether I use mouse click or the `V`/`v` operator. Nothing on the system clipboard will be left once I enter the visual mode.

PS: I did not find `mswin` in my `_vimrc`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, thanks to Ben's advice on `guioptions`.

Remove the following line:

```
set guioptions+=a
```

And make sure that `<C-C>` is behaving "normally". (Normally as for windows OS.)

```
vnoremap <C-C> "+y
```

The second mapping means to "feed onto system clipboard".

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you either have an 'a' in your `'guioptions'` option, or you have "autoselect" in your `'clipboard'` option.

Check the output of this command to see which is the case and then fix it accordingly:

```
:verbose set clipboard? guioptions?
```

Comment: Yes, I did have an `a` in the guioptions.